# Java Random Between Variables

Tags: java, function, random, methods, int

I'm trying to randomize between these 3 variables (not range, but only between these 3 values) and store it into new variable.

```
int randomProductDiscount() {

    int disc1 = 25;
    int disc2 = 35;
    int disc3 = 50;

    int productDiscount = (random between disc1 or disc2 or disc3);

    return productDiscount;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put your 3 variables in an array, pick a random index in your array (between 0 and 2 (inclusive)) and use that as your new variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put them in an array and obtain random index:

```
static Random rand = new Random();

int randomProductDiscount()
{
    int[] disc = {25,35,50}; 
    return disc[rand.nextInt(disc.length)];
}
```

This can be used for any number of values you wish to choose randomly from.